# Manage Google Apps Scripts' permissions in one place on my Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have currently made a site with over 100 Google Apps Scripts. These work fine for me, but whenever another user enters my site this user has to accept the permissions required for each of them separately. How can I make it so that my users can do this in one general place for all scripts on my site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have more than one doget() and dopost() handlers on different scripts?

Comment: @MShoaib91 No, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having 100 differents scripts, you should only have one script that identify where it's launch from with something like  `var url = SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl();` and then you decide to display value according to the page where you are.

Comment: Thanks a lot though, really helped me out! When I use .getName() the code isn't even that worse.